# Is it preferable to expose a C library to Elixir/Erlang, or to implement in Erlang/Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, beam

My background's in Perl/Python/node and a smattering of Ruby. I've not used BEAM VM languages before.

In Perl/Python/Node/Ruby, if I wanted to handle 'lower level' tasks - intense compute, needing access to threads, or more commonly, wrapping a C library - I'd write something in C. Elixir/Erlang obviously has great parallelism in the form of Erlang processes and very low latency, eliminating much of that need.

So **if I had a C library, would it be preferable to make an Elixir/Erlang wrapper or just reimplement the functionality?**

A very specific example: does Elixir/Erlang's TLS use OpenSSL, or is it implemented in a BEAM language?

Comment: You're asking for a generic answer.  Can you narrow the question a bit?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I'm asking what the idiomatic approach would be - for something more specific, see the example already given in the question re: TLS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual way to implement things in Erlang is to implement it in Erlang first, then measure it. If it doesn't perform well, look for improvement in Erlang first. If it is not still good enough, rewrite hot parts in C. You can use [ports](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html) as a safer way or [NIFs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html) if data transfer would kill it. The rationale behind is that Erlang (or Elixir as well) provide a great environment for writing simple, safe code. It provides great exception handling and support for reliability. You can think about Erlang as a domain specific language for writing server service and container for handling concurrent tasks and distributing load to CPUs and executed in high performing small chunks of code in another language. The less code you have to implement in the other language than Erlang/Elixir the better.

If you think about binary protocol handling as low level, definitely try implement it in Erlang because bit manipulation syntax in Erlang is just amazing.

And yes, TLS is mostly written in Erlang (key handling, IO, ...) with performance critical parts in C (hash and crypto algorithms).

One of very good advice is: Always measure, don't expect. You can even see a nontrivial solution that performs better implemented in pure Erlang than in C++. See [Comparing Cpp And Erlang For Motorola Telecoms Software](http://www.slideshare.net/Arbow/comparing-cpp-and-erlang-for-motorola-telecoms-software).